# Unclear issue with fork(), possibly with source file?

Tags: c, fork

I'm a beginner programmer to C and I'm trying to write a basic shell. I'm trying to use the fork() function, but it simply doesn't seem to work. I get caught in an endless loop of just my shell's prompt taking input and then seemingly doing nothing with it.

I ran the debugger and set the breakpoint to where the program forks, and at that point, I got an error message of

```
Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-Cl5G7W/glibc-2.23/posix/../sysdeps/nptl/fork.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

What I think is happening is that I either messed up with my #include headers or that when I tried to compile, I left some library out. I've just been compiling with the standard

```
gcc -o shell custom_shell.c
```

and I recall my teacher saying something about compiling with libraries, but I thought my #include headers would cover that and I can't find anything else on the topic online.

The parts of my code I'm wary over are

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

...

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid < 0){ //error
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
}

else if (pid == 0){ //child
    execvp(args[0], args);
}

else{ //parent
    wait(0);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your intention is with execvp(args[0], ...). What are you attempting to execute?

Comment: @Makketronix Sorry, forgot to clarify that! Earlier in the code I've got a bit that asks for user input and tokenizes it into this args array. The first element is the process and the next one(s) are the arguments (e.g. sleep 300). Honestly, I haven't even gotten around to that bit yet, so it didn't occur to me that I should've included that part as well.

Comment: You need to deal with `execvp()` failing!

Comment: There simply isn’t enough information here for us to be able to help.  You need to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That makes sense, but for now I can't even get my process to fork.

Comment: Instead of args[0], replace that with what you think should be correct input. If it works, you know your args[0] is not what you expect. If it doesn't work, then you have something specific and clear to ask. Also, please create a small program (main.c) file, which we can copy and paste to test :D. Help us help you!

Comment: @Makketronix You were right, I played around with your suggestion and found that there was actually an error in the tokenizing I'd omitted that I was oh so confident. From what I can tell, there's no way to mark a comment as a best answer, but your comment basically helped perfectly, so thank you! :D

Comment: I am glad it helped. Assumptions always have the potential to stab you in the back in software. Keep an opened mind and rule over the digital world.